# Htc one m7 International not recognized in adb mode

Tags: adb, htc, fastboot, sim-unlocking, troubleshooting

I have an htc one m7 running bootloader hboot 1.56.
I unlocked the bootloader via htcdev.com
The bootloader now shows *Unlocked*
My phone is recognized in adb when the phone is turned on.
But when i go into the bootloader and get into the fastboot mode, the command "adb devices" returns blank in the command prompt.

I have reinstalled the htc drivers thrice already. Twice using the latest version of HTC Sync Manager and once separately from a link on xda.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Can somebody tell me where I might have gone wrong?

P.s. - Running windows 7 x64

Answer (score 3):

You don't use `adb` to connect to a device when it's in the bootloader menu: you need to use the `fastboot` command instead. That's why it's called "fastboot mode"! Not all phones support `fastboot`: in particular, older HTC phones use a proprietary protocol called HBOOT instead, but I think the newer ones support `fastboot`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out after an hour of searching with different keywords. I'd been out of the rooting game for a while, got confused between the two.

- **Fastboot in bootloader mode did work.**
- **adb does not work in bootloader.**

Thanks for the answer Dan, much appreciated.